# How to do the limited record searching?

Tags: php, mysql, range

Please help me. In this code, the user will type a number. Then after submitting the input, the only records that it should be searching at is from ID numbers 1 to 143 only (excluding numbers 144 and up). How can I do it? Is it like a range? How? Thanks!

```
<?php


$prevalue = $_POST['id_checknumber'];






$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM demo WHERE id_ln = '$prevalue'");

$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);



if ($prevalue <= 10){ 
    echo "<script>
             alert('Loric Number $prevalue has already been taken by a Garde.'); 
             window.history.go(-1);
    </script>";}
    else {
if ($numrows!=0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $id_ln = $row['id_ln'];
   $id_email = $row['id_email'];
   $id_firstname = $row['id_firstname']; 
   $id_lastname = $row['id_lastname']; 
   echo "<script>
             alert('Hi, $id_firstname $id_lastname! Your registered Loric Number is $id_ln. Thanks!'); 
             window.history.go(-1);
    </script>";
}}


if ($numrows===0){echo"<script>
             alert('Hi! This number is not yet registered. Register now! Go back to the main menu!'); 
             window.history.go(-1);
    </script>";
    }
}

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: Add a `LIMIT` clause to your query.

Comment: That seems like a rather arbitrary constraint; it might be better to just filter out disallowed values in code before even querying. As far as I can tell from the information you've given, doing so in the query won't help it's speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM demo WHERE id_ln = '$prevalue' AND id_ln <= 143");
```

I think this should answer your question, but as people have already said in the comments, it'd be a better idea to just disallow values higher than 143 before even attempting the query.

Unless of course you only want the first 143 records returned, then it would look like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM demo WHERE id_ln = '$prevalue' LIMIT 143");
```

Comment: Awesome, again though I want to emphasis that you should also be limiting the user at the UI level from entering in any numbers greater than 143 to prevent most confusion. Happy to know this helped though!